# How can I set a program as a child of another? Windows

Tags: windows, automation

I'd like a program to automatically run if a different program is running, and close when that one closes.

For example: If I start Google Chrome, then Photoshop starts, as soon as I close Chrome, it acts as a killswitch and shuts down Photoshop.

(but if I just start/stop Photoshop that doesn't necessarily start/stop chrome)

(I'm looking for a way/program to make this automatic - not need to run a batch file or whatever every time)

Comment: You can start launch Chrome from a batch file with `start /wait ...`: when this completes the batch file can make any post-execution checks you need. Alternatively you can use the freeware [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to set up an action when a process completes.

Comment: @AFH Sorry, I'm trying to make it that (for this example) Photoshop will only start if chrome is open, and it will automatically close if I close Chrome.

(Even If I open chrome in a normal way - not through a  batch file or whatever

Comment: In that case run PhotoShop from a batch file using `start` without `/wait` and follow it with `nircmd waitprocess chrome.exe` to run `closeprocess photoshop.exe` (or `killprocess`, depending on how unfriendly you want to be). Note: the `exe` names are probably incorrect in this example.